# Mounting the GCP Cloud Storage bucket to Directory as a non-root user

Tags: linux, file-permissions, gcp, gcsfuse

I'm running the one service on the Linux based instance in GCP.

So for running the service, i have created the one user & group for that i.e.;
user: test-user
group: test-group

Then i need to mount the one directory to the GCS bucket. For that purpose,

- i have installed the gcsfuse on machine
- created the one directory
- mount the GCS bucket to directory
- tried to allow a non-root user (e.g., mirth-user) to access the mounted GCS bucket, adjusted permissions i.e.; ***sudo usermod -aG fuse test-user***

but it doesn't take those modifications.

Can anyone help on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try referring to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md#permissions-and-ownership ? And did that help answer your question ?

Comment: I have executed the task by using the below command

Create the Group & user:

- sudo groupadd group-name

Adding user to the Group:

- sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false -g group-name user-name

Mounting the Bucket to the Directory:

- sudo mount -t gcsfuse -o implicit_dirs,allow_other,uid=<id_value>,gid=<gid_value> <bucket> <path>